# How is the dichromate anion generated from potassium dichromate?

Tags: aqueous-solution, ions, ionic-compounds

How does $\ce{K2Cr2O7}$ become $\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$ when dissolved in water?

Comment: Questions based on related concept: [How to determine which ions will pair to form a compound in an aqueous solution?](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/96387) and [Acid-base reaction vs. salt dissolving reaction](//chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/92379)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't seem to be overly familiar with the concepts of salts (made of cations and anions), ionic bonds and solvation of salts in water.

Lets's walk through some examples in which a solid material made from cations and anions is dissolved in water in such a way that the anions and cations are each surrounded and stabilized by water molecules (i.e. they are in an *aqueous* state, denoted as *aq*):

$$\begin{align}
\ce{NaCl (s) &->[H2O] Na+ (aq) + Cl- (aq)} \\
\ce{MgSO4 (s) &->[H2O] Mg^2+ (aq) + SO4^2- (aq)} \\
\ce{Na2SO4 (s) &->[H2O] 2Na+ (aq) + SO4^2- (aq)} \\
\ce{K3PO4 (s) &->[H2O] 3K+ (aq) + PO4^3- (aq)} \\
\ce{Mg3(PO4)2 (s) &->[H2O] 3Mg^2+ (aq) + 2PO4^3- (aq)}
\end{align}$$

As a general rule for the solvation of the salts, we can derive:

$$\ce{M_mX_n (s) ->[H2O] mM^n+ (aq) + nX^m- (aq)}$$

Applying this to potassium dichromate, we recognise that the cation is $\ce{K+}$ and the anion is $\ce{Cr2O7^2-}$. Therefore, it is the *dissolution* of potassium dichromate in water which generates the dichromate anion:

$$\ce{K2Cr2O7 (s) ->[H2O] 2K+ (aq) + Cr2O7^2- (aq)}$$

As for the physical reason behind why the salts dissolve, you may find a more in-depth discussion here: [Why do salts such as NaCl dissolve?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5915/16683)