# Why does Fluorine have a high affinity for Calcium?

Tags: metal, ionic-compounds, halides

I keep hearing from several websites and videos that Fluorine seems to like bonding to Calcium specifically; can someone please tell me why? I can't seem to find a clear response on the internet. Fluorine has a high affinity to Calcium, more than other elements. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not the question of affinity but insolubility of CaF2. As this salt has solubility product of ~4×10−11 which is mostly caused by nice packing and strong ionic interaction (*see* [enter link description here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/why-do-salts-such-as-nacl-dissolve))

Comment: The free energy of formation is also quite negative. Combined with the low solubility, it indicates that it will readily form and will not go in to solution, so once formed it is quite happy as is.